# Como anido WHERE en LARAVEL?

Tags: laravel

no lo consigo, es un render de LIVEWIRE que tiene una condicion principal que es Cod_Client y en un input tiene que filtrar por N_Factura, Fecha_Factura e Importe_Total. este seria en SQL:

```
SELECT [Cod_Clien],[N_Factura] FROM [factor].[dbo].[catfact_the]
WHERE [Cod_Clien]='90921' and
  ([N_Factura] like '%%' or
   [Fecha_Factura] like '%%' or
   [Importe_Factura] like'%%')
```

y lo que tengo pero no funciona:

```
$facturas = Factura::where('Cod_Clien',auth()->user()->cod_client)
                        ->where('N_Factura','LIKE','%' . $this->search . '%')
                        ->orWhere('Fecha_Factura','LIKE','%' . $this->search . '%')
                        ->orWhere('Importe_Factura','LIKE','%' . $this->search . '%')
                        ->paginate();

                return view('livewire.admin.facturas-index',compact('facturas'));
```

El problema que no filtra por Cod_Client y me los muestra todos.
Gracias por cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba tu consulta de esta forma:

```
Factura::where('Cod_Clien',auth()->user()->cod_client)
    ->where(function ($query) {
             $query->where('N_Factura','LIKE','%' . $this->search . '%')
                   ->orWhere('Fecha_Factura','LIKE','%' . $this->search . '%')
                   ->orWhere('Importe_Factura','LIKE','%' . $this->search . '%');
    })->paginate();
```

Puedes leer mas en la [doc.](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#or-where-clauses) sobre como agrupar varios `or` en una consulta dentro de paréntesis.

Comment: Muchas gracias BetaM, funciona perfectamente, una vez visto parece sencillo pero no lo conseguía, me falta mucha practica..

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que la query original utiliza OR dentro de un paréntesis. Cuando haces

```
        WHERE X and (Y or Z)
```

Es distinto a

```
        WHERE X and Y or Z
```

Donde se cumple para toda combinación  `X o Y o Z`, y que es lo que ocurre hoy en tu objeto QueryBuilder.

Para aislar el alcance de `orWhere` puedes usar a tu ventaja lo que sugiere [@BetaM](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/128299/betam) y poner un closure como argumento del segundo `where`. Sólo para mayor abundamiento, se me ocurren otras dos maneras para mencionar

#### Dynamic Scopes

Un [dynamic scope](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#dynamic-scopes) puede ser ligeramente más trabajoso que la solución ya planteada, pero una vez que se les agarra la mano se paga el esfuerzo.

En tu modelo `Factura` declaras un método público cuyo nombre esté en camelCase y empiece por `scope`. En mi caso le puse `scopeMatchingSearch`.

```
/**
 * Scope para buscar por texto parcial en N_Factura, 
 * Fecha_Factura e Importe_Factura
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
 * @param  string  $search
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
  public function scopeMatchingSearch($query, $search) {
         return $query
              ->where('N_Factura','LIKE', $search)
              ->orWhere('Fecha_Factura','LIKE', $search)
              ->orWhere('Importe_Factura','LIKE', $search);
  }
```

Luego en tu controller puedes llamarlo quitando el `scope` y siempre en camelCase (o sea `matchingSearch`).

```
  $facturas = Factura::where('Cod_Clien',auth()->user()->cod_client)
                  ->matchingSearch('%' . $this->search . '%')
                  ->paginate();
```

Si te fijas, la convención es que dado un scope

```
  public function scopeMetodoEnCamelCase($query, $parametro1) {}
```

Yo puedo usarlo como

```
  Modelo::metodoEnCamelCase($parametro1)->etc etc
```

O sea: omito el parámetro $query (Eloquent se preocupa de anteponerlo a tus parámetros) y el prefijo `scope`.

#### Concatenación

Tu query original puede expresarse como

```
SELECT [Cod_Clien],[N_Factura] FROM [factor].[dbo].[catfact_the]
  WHERE [Cod_Clien]='90921' AND
  CONCAT([N_Factura],' ',[Fecha_Factura],' ',[Importe_Factura]) like '%123%'
```

Puedes utilizar el modo raw para que eloquent no intente modificar lo que es una función de SQLServer

```
  $facturas = Factura::where('Cod_Clien',auth()->user()->cod_client)
        ->whereRaw(
             "CONCAT(N_Factura,' ',Fecha_Factura,' ',Importe_Factura) LIKE ?",
             ['%' . $this->search . '%']
        ) 
        ->paginate();
```

Que es igual a usar

```
  $facturas = Factura::where('Cod_Clien',auth()->user()->cod_client)
        ->where(
            DB::raw("CONCAT(N_Factura,' ',Fecha_Factura,' ',Importe_Factura)") 
           'LIKE',
           '%' . $this->search . '%'
        ) 
        ->paginate();
```

(pero recuerda poner `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;`en alguna parte para usar ese facade)

Comment: Hola, la solución de BetaM ha funcionado perfectamente, pero probaré tus sugerencias sobre todo para aprender mas opciones, muchas gracias..